# Read XML element from free geo location service

Tags: xml, vb.net, linq

[This](http://freegeoip.net/) is free service to get geo location of an ip address.

I've build a class function to get the xml response. Here is the code.

```
    Public Shared Function GetGeoLocation(ByVal IpAddress As String) As String    
        Using client = New WebClient()
            Try
                Dim strFile = client.DownloadString(String.Format("http://freegeoip.net/xml/{0}", IpAddress))

                Dim xml As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(strFile)
                Dim responses = From response In xml.Descendants("Response")
                                Select New With {response.Element("CountryName").Value}
                                Take 1

                Return responses.ElementAt(0).ToString()
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return "Default"
            End Try
        End Using
    End Function
```

Requesting the request I don't face any problem. The problem is to read return request from the service. For example, ip address [180.73.24.99](http://freegeoip.net/xml/180.73.24.99) will return this value:

```
<Response>
<Ip>180.73.24.99</Ip>
<CountryCode>MY</CountryCode>
<CountryName>Malaysia</CountryName>
<RegionCode>01</RegionCode>
<RegionName>Johor</RegionName>
<City>Tebrau</City><ZipCode/>
<Latitude>1.532</Latitude>
<Longitude>103.7549</Longitude>
<MetroCode/>
<AreaCode/>
</Response>
```

And my function `GetGeoLocation(180.73.24.99)` will return `{ Value = Malaysia }`. How can I fix this function to only return `Malaysia`. I guess its something wrong with my linq statement.

**Solution**

```
Dim responses = From response In xml.Descendants("Response")
                Select response.Element("CountryName").Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning this `Select New With {response.Element("CountryName").Value}` anonymous object, simply return value of `CountryName` element:

```
Select response.Element("CountryName").Value
```

Also I suggest you to use `FirstOrDefault` instead of taking first item.

```
Dim xdoc = XDocument.Parse(strFile)
Dim countries = From r In xdoc...<Response>
                Select r.<CountryName>.Value
Return If(countries.FirstOrDefault(), "Default")
```

Or even in one line

```
Return If(xdoc...<Response>.<CountryName>.FirstOrDefault(), "Default")
```

Comment: Need more details on `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Okay I got it.

`Return responses.FirstOrDefault.ToString()`

Comment: @Ekin I've updated sample with `FirstOrDefault` usage - you just check with `If(query.FirstOrDefault(), "Default")` if there any results. And if no, then return default value.